# should the push server support https for apns?

Tags: ssl, https, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

A stupid question, as I have a bad head for HTTPS and SSLs.

The question is simple. As I've read at [Apple APNS guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1), there is required a SSL certificate. Should this certificate be linked only with my App ID or it should somehow represent my server to the WEB?

In other words: is it possible to set up the push-server over the HTTP, or it should be **HTTPS only**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificate is needed to verify/identify the sender and the app where push will be send to.

From article [Certificate-Based Provider-to-APNs Trust](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

> A certificate-based provider connection is valid for delivery to one specific app, identified by the topic (the app bundle ID) specified in the provider certificate (which you must have previously created, as explained in “Generate a universal APNs client SSL certificate” in Xcode Help)

To answer on your question:

> > Should this certificate be linked only with my App ID or it should somehow represent my server to the WEB?
> >     It have to be linked with your app id. And it is used to setup secure connection between your server(PN provider) and Apple Push Notifications server (for sending request from server to APNS)